# How to Fix Python Multiprocessing Pool Stall

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use Python's multiprocessing to write some parallel code.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work at all the second the code hits the pool's initialization.  It works perfectly fine in debug mode, but gets stuck running normally and I have to manually terminate it to stop it.

I've tried using the multiprocess library instead, to no avail.  I've surfed the web for days trying to find anything that helps, to no avail.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def foo(x):
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('starting')
    pool = Pool(1)
    print('pool created')
    result = pool.map(foo,[1,2,3])
    print('done mapping')
    print(result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('final done')
```

I expected the output to be like so:

```
starting
pool created
done mapping
[1, 2, 3]
final done
```

Which is what I get when I run using WIng IDE's integrated debugger.  When I run the program normally, I get this:

```
starting
```

Followed by an infinite loop that locks me out.
Let me know if I need to add anything to this post, it's my first and I'm not used to these forums.

I'm using Windows 10 Education 1803 build 17134.706 on a notebook.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It works fine to me.

Comment: What OS are you using?  I'll add it in, but I'm using Windows on a quad core notebook.

Comment: that looks pretty standard usage of the module and I've done similar things many times, under Linux and OSX, hence I presume it's a OS specific issue.  maybe try installing a different version of Python?

Comment: (just to confirm, I tried your code under Python 3.7.3 and 2.7.16 and both were fine under Linux)

Comment: Which Python version exactly? Have you tried running it from terminal?

Comment: @LordeDracus it runs fine on Windows 7.